# how to add dynamic sidebar to a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add two extra dynamic sidebar to my Wordpress theme above blog posts adjacent to each other, by the way alignment is from right to left, any help is previously appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Can you be a little more specific? Here's how to make your theme widget ready:

**functions.php**

```
// register sidebars
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
        register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Left Sidebar', //Name your sidebar
        'description' => 'These widgets will appear in the left sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">', // Displays before widget
        'after_widget' => '</div>', // Displayed after widget
        'before_title' => '<h3>', //Displays before title, after widget start
        'after_title' => '</h3>' //Displays after title
    ));
```

Then place this wherever your sidebar will appear:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Name Here') ) : ?>
    <!-- static content goes here if sidebar is inactive -->
<?php endif; ?>
```